# Regex to parse key value string with withspace in value

Tags: regex

I need to parse a key-value string.
The regex should get the text after whitespace (red line) in the second capture group (value).

Currently used regex:

```
([^=\s,]+)=([^\s\,]+)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `([^=\s,]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|([^\s,]+))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to deal with the edge case of the key being in quotation marks would be to use an alternation:

```
\b([^=]+)=(?:"(.*?)"|([^\s,]+))
```

This matches a key, followed by `=`, then following by either:

```
"(.*?)"    a term in double quotes (capture only what is inside quotes)
|          OR
[^\s,]+    any continuous block of non whitespace characters (non quote case)
```

### Demo